# How to hide the files listing index page of a MinIO bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I had installed **Minio** Server for object storage in my ubuntu machine. I have a specific scenario:

My Minio version is "RELEASE.2021-05-26T19-19-26Z" [2 years back I had installed]

I have a bucket named as "home-bucket".

Under this "home-bucket", I have hundreds of files like images/videos/docs etc.

https://example.com:9000/home-bucket/

It opens up the whole file listing and shows as ListBucketResults, which actually lists all the items inside the bucket.

[image]

But I do not want it. I want if someone clicks the above url, he should be redirected to the login page or should say access denied.

But any particular item inside that bucket should be accessible to download if somone hits any specific filestorage url like below:

https://example.com:9000/home-bucket/1175352120547693431?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=testadmin%2F20231030%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231030T074937Z&X-Amz-Expires=432000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=56781a1c1d0b60a10d5212720c7017bc7c3ec23cfb416f8e2d91a5e6e9fwes1

I want to set a policy for that.

My current policies look like below:

[image]

I don't want to show this file listing page, but I want all files inside the bucket to be world-readable. How to setup policy for that? Or any simple tweak for that? Please remember my Minio version is "RELEASE.2021-05-26T19-19-26Z"